# Displaying Toast alert to user based on validation from controller

Tags: c, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am trying to see what would be the best way to approach this. I am using MVC .Net Core Web App.

When a user clicks a "Create Ticket" button, it checks to see how many tickets are open. If more than 5 tickets are open, then display toast alert message. If not, then create ticket.

```
 public IActionResult Create()
    {
     var ticket = _context.tickets
                 .where(x => x.statusID == "1") //1 = open

      if(ticket.Count() > 5){
         //from my research many people use tempData here
         TempData["Alert"] = "You have exceeded limit"
         return ? //What do I return???
        }

     Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
     _context.ticket.Add(ticket);
     _context.ticket.SaveChanges();

     return RedirectToAction("Index");


}
```

I want to display the alert without **refreshing** the page. Will the best approach be to do an Ajax call when button is clicked? If so, would it look like this

```
 $(function () {
        $("#Createbtn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Tickets/CreateValidation",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
            })
        })
    })
```

Then from the action I can redirect to "Create" action? 
I appreciate the input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to return message to the client ajax success function, you should return OKresult in your controller method.

Besides, since you use ajax to call the method function, it will return the index html makeup instead of redirect to the index method when you call RedirectToAction.

In my opinion, you should check the message in the client success function. If the return message is a url, you should use `window.location.href` to redirect to the returned url.

Details, you could refer to below codes:

```
[Route("Tickets/CreateValidation")]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    //      var ticket = _context.tickets
    //                  .where(x => x.statusID == "1") //1 = open

    //if (ticket.Count() > 5)
    //      {
    //          //from my research many people use tempData here
    //          TempData["Alert"] = "You have exceeded limit"
    //   return ? //What do I return???
    //  }

    //      Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    //      _context.ticket.Add(ticket);
    //      _context.ticket.SaveChanges();

    //      return RedirectToAction("Index");

    //I don't have your dbcontext, so I create a ticket number directly
    var ticketnumber = 4;

    if (ticketnumber >5)
    {
        //If we want to return string  to the client side inside a post action method, we could directly using OK or Json as the result.
        //If we use OK to return data, the we could receive this data inside the ajax success method
        return Ok("You have exceeded limit");
    }

    return Ok("/Default/Index");

}
```

Client-side ajax:

```
    $(function () {
        $("#Createbtn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Tickets/CreateValidation",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "/Default/Index") {
                        window.location.href = data;
                    } else {
                        alert(data);
                    }

                } 
            })
        })
    })

</script>
```

Result:

If the ticket number > 5:

[image]

If the ticket number <5:

You could find the page has refreshed.

[image]